# count of maximum numbers of records in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
id      ownerid     title

1       1           a
2       1           b
3       2           c
4       3           d
5       3           e
5       3           f
```

Now i want to find count of maximum records of ownerid. means in above example, there is 2 records for ownerid 1, 1 record for ownerid 2 and 3 records for ownerid 3. So output should be `3`.

So how to do that?

SQL :

```
SELECT count(ownerid) FROM `tblowner` group by ownerid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by`

```
SELECT count(ownerid) as tot 
FROM `tblowner` 
group by ownerid 
order by tot desc limit 1;
```